# Problem installing Quartus II in ubuntu

Tags: virtualbox

I am trying to install quartus II in ubuntu
and getting the following error

Not enough space left in . (3386084 KB) to decompress 11.0sp1_quartus_free_linux.sh (3465364 KB)

I tried solution given in 
[VirtualBox Ubuntu: Not enough space left in /tmp to decompress VBoxLinuxAdditions.run](https://askubuntu.com/questions/430124/virtualbox-ubuntu-not-enough-space-left-in-tmp-to-decompress-vboxlinuxaddition)

But could not get solution please help

regards

Comment: Not enough space; means your 'disk' (virtual or real) is full.  You need to delete something to create space.  The "." is shorthand for your current directory ($PWD), so you need space in whichever drive/partition your current directory is in.  ps:  3386084KB is rather large; so I'd check your 'download' or whatever you're trying to decompress is correct; and not corrupt.

Comment: @uzmeed check MD5 of your downloaded file - it should be  [105c88a866ec3428cae30f3905b47f46 ( *11.0sp1_quartus_free_linux.sh*, 3.3 Gb)](https://www.altera.com/downloads/software/quartus-ii-we/110sp1.html) (from Altera web-site). Also please add output of `df -h` to the question. You run out of space consider to move installation media outside VM or grow disk partition.

Comment: Thank N0rbert output of the df -h is  Filesystem        Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev              972M     0  972M   0% /dev
tmpfs             200M  3.6M  196M   2% /run
/dev/sda1          18G   14G  3.3G  81% /
tmpfs             997M  220K  997M   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs             5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs             997M     0  997M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
quartus           293G  168G  126G  58% /media/sf_quartus
tlut_flow-master  293G  168G  126G  58% /media/sf_tlut_flow-master

Comment: tmpfs             200M   52K  200M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sr0           56M   56M     0 100% /media/uzmeed/VBox_GAs_5.2.14
I have seen the download its complete and OK .                                                      guiverc i have my new lap top with quite less data

Comment: I have seen my download is complete and OK . I ve lot more space as my laptop is new with lots of space available. and i have recencently creared VM this is my first download

Comment: I created the VM with 20 GB but now got to know that i need 75+GB please guide how can I do this